# Firefox && IE TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to display a highchart graph and when rendering in FF or IE, I get the above error, but in Chrome and Safari I works without fail. I think it is to do with the animation, but switching the animation off, then subsequently works for line charts, but pie charts does not show a chart at all.

```
$(canvas).highcharts({
    chart : {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    colors: ["#7cb5ec", "#f7a35c", "#90ee7e", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
        "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
    credits: {
        enabled: true
    },
    title : {
        text: title
    },
    plotOptions : {
      series : {
          animation : isWebkit()
      }
    },
    series: data
});
```

......

Comment: show us a bit of your code

Comment: I have edited the question with the sample of code that is causing me the issues, as I say, it works perfectly in webkit browsers, but IE and FF, not so much.

Comment: Just tried, works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/542ja/8/ - maybe your function `iseWebkit()` throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help,  I am still having the issues, but I have coded around it for now.  I am sure there is lots I did not tell you in my original question that would influence the answer (such as I am using bootstrap as my UI platform, and the chart is in a tab which is not visible when it is built, also on the page is a spreadJS control, and looking at the stack trace, this might have an influence and finally the data object would need expanding as I am setting more options than just the values in your jsfiddle example), so I think it is better if I ask the question again once I can expose the other challenges on the page.
So, again thank you, and I will need to ask the question more clearly.

Comment: And the solution was?!